# How to fetch data from a web service into array and then store in database without exhausting memory limit?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get large amount of (category) features (data) from a web service. It takes quite a long time (response time and so on take more then 5 hours) to get all data on the web service. But I get "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" error after the first hour.

I have categories stored in my local db. To get the features of an category I simply use the id of that category and the service returns me the features of that category. I could store that returned data immediately into the db but then I would not be able to use the features as long as the whole process takes.

Instead I am trying to store all result data into an array and after the whole loop is over store all the array to the db. That way the features will only blocked as long as the writing takes (about 5min).

to show it roughly:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    $features = $webService->getCategoryFeatures($category->id);
    // ...and some other logics
}

foreach($features = $feature){
    App\Feature::create($feature);
    // ...and some other logics
}
```

There are about 4000 categories. Some categories have more than 30000 features. So the first sequence takes quite a long time. The second sequence where I just store the data into the db takes just some minutes.

I need a way where I can temporarily store the returned features without getting memory error. Besides I don't want to increase the limit.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So you need all the category features before a category is selected?  That does sound like a lot of data.  Obviously its not ideal to replicate an entire webservice beforehand in your own database, how would you know if there were changes to the category features you’re about to display?  Have you considered another approach, (like only getting features for a selected category?

Comment: You completely right. It is not clever to replicate the web service data. But I need to perform some methods that the web service does not provide. Such as searching among the features or count of features etc. And yes I would not know of any updates thus I was thinking to use this process and update daily. Yep I am looking for other approaches but if I get only the selected category's features then I wont be able to make search operations.

Comment: Is there no endpoint for handling a feature search etc?  I think you might talk to your webservice provider explaining what you’re trying to implement, maybe there’s a way you haven’t considered or that’s undocumented, heck they might even add the endpoint.  TBH how to proceed from here depends almost entirely on the webservice provider (and tricks like downloading and separately maintaining a copy of their db should be only considered if there is absolutely no other approach).

Comment: I tried to get support about changes but without luck. Contacting the web service for changes is hopeless. They have only 3 methods for the features which are all the same. That is why I want the data locally. I can be flexible and independent if I replicate the whole data.

Comment: @James actually I am looking into redis and memchached. Do you have any experience or ideas if they could help me. I mean instead storing into an array I could temporarily store on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I came up with a simple solution. I created a temporary  (categoryies_temp) table and started the whole process with this table. So even it takes a long time the original table will still be operational.

After the process is completed I first truncated the table and then simply copy all the temp records to the original table which takes just some seconds. I know this may seem a simple way but definitely effective.

Answer (score 0):

make the web service return limited records with input of page number. call the web service with incrementing page number and store the result obtained in database. call again with next page number till you get 0 result from a page number. stop calling web service after that.

Comment: If I store the result right after each call to the service, then the features will be useless until the whole process it completed. Besides the pagination is not a problem here.

Comment: you are getting 30000 data in one go via api. instead whatever operations you want to do, do on server and create more api outlets if needed. api should give minimal and essential data to mobile and besides you cant expect users to view 30000 data, if you want to process it and show few, that is different case, and in this case you have to do that processing on server.

Comment: I am not getting them in one go, of course they come in 100 records per page. Besides I am not showing them to the user at the first place. The service does not provide any additional functions other than calling them. I am storing them to the database. So I can make searches and other stuff on my server.

Comment: you need to use the concept called syncing. sync the data in background with web services periodically like once in every hour. or once a day. here too, you can make an optimisation by using flags, only sync the required data by putting proper flags. put flag to sync only when data is updated to avoid repeated processing of same data. first time, sync all data and mark all rows as in sync. whenever the row is updated, unmark it. and in api, only send unmarked data